# a switch bug in swift? - "Switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause."

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I am positive that the following **swift** code has covered all possibilities, but Xcode keeps telling me that, **"Switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause."**

Can anyone tell me what did I miss? Thanks.

```
let a = false
let b = false
let c = false

func test(a: Bool, _ b: Bool, _ c: Bool) {
    switch (a, b, c) {
    case (true, false, _):
        print("Moved left!!!")
    case (true, true, _):
        print("Moved right!!!")
    case (false, _, false):
        print("Moved up!!!")
    case (false, _, true):
        print("Moved down!!!")
    // Error: Switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause.
    }
}

test(false, false, false)
test(false, false, true)
test(false, true, false)
test(false, true, true)
test(true, false, false)
test(true, false, true)
test(true, true, false)
test(true, true, true)
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is unable to conclude about your pattern because it is too complex or too unusual for it. If your pattern would have been more regular like:

```
case (true, false, _):
    print("Moved left!!!")
case (true, true, _):
    print("Moved right!!!")
case (false, false, _):
    print("Moved up!!!")
case (false, true, _):
    print("Moved down!!!")
```

then the compiler would have not complained. It that case it is easy for it to conclude that you covered all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, a `switch` statement must always provide an option for all possible cases. If you have an enum, you can add all enum values and the `switch` will be exhaustive. If it is not exhaustive, you need to add a `default` case, this will trigger when no other case is matched.

If you are switching on a variable, you should exhaust all cases. If you do that, a `default` case is not needed.

A programmer might be able to see that this switch is exhaustive, but the compiler does not. That is why you get the error, and you can fix it by adding a default case.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate all the possible combinations between three elements with two possible values, the cases are more than four. If you don't care about the others, put a `default` case in your switch

Comment: The `_` _(the wildcard pattern)_ covers the “missing cases”.  Each of the `case`s in the question covers two possibilities — the `_` can be any value, so either `true` or `false` here — for a total of all 8 _(2³)_ possibilities covered.