# Why can't Swift figure out that UInt % 2 has only two possible values?

Tags: swift

```
var count: UInt

switch count % 2
{
case 0:
    // do something

case 1:
    // do something else
}
```

Warning at closing `}` is `Switch must be exhaustive, consider a default clause`.

Why can't Swift figure this out?

Comment: It isn't true! `(-1) % 2 == -1`

Comment: @MartinR Oops, good point. Edit: Same for `UInt`. BTW, adding `case -1:` did not help.

Comment: @meaning-matters why don't you create an enumeration with two cases odd and even with a initializer that takes an Int and switch that?

Comment: @LeoDabus Because I only want to add code that's needed.

Comment: @meaning-matters how about if count % 2 == 0

Comment: `switch count % 2 == 0` ;  `case false:` ; `case true:`

Comment: The Swift compiler does not figure out the mathematics behind `%`. You can add a `default: fatalError()` to make the compiler (and you?) happy.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Because I want my code to show it's a symmetrical case. (Very important programming rule: Keep things as meaningful as possible.)

Comment: @MartinR I got that. But my question remains: Why not? C compilers used to do this a long time ago.

Comment: @vadian I know there are other ways.

Comment: Does the (Xcode/Clang) C compiler ever emit a warning if you switch on an `int` value? – Anyway: File a bug report if it bothers you!

Comment: It's probably a question of performance. Unlike in C you can switch on almost everything in Swift and it's quite expensive to check for the possible number of cases with complex mathematical expressions at compile time.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762108/a-switch-bug-in-swift-switch-must-be-exhaustive-consider-adding-a-default-c and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476599/swift-switch-statement-considered-all-cases-of-int-but-compiler-still-display-e are more cases where the compiler does not figure out that the cases are exhaustive.

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, no warning with similar code I quickly typed in Obj-C module. Anyway, this is something I've learned to not expect in the old days with C compilers.

Comment: @MartinR Great SO post. I think I just have to live with the new Swift reality :-)  I'll change my code to something suggested above.